# VStack inside ScrollView swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scroll, expand, vstack

I have view, where inside ScrollView stackView, with content what expand after tap on button, and then I should scroll this page. in the bottom I have HStack with buttons, up there "RatingViews".
I need to make the buttons from the last HStack always be at the bottom, and always have the same indentation. before expanding and after that.

they should be offset 8 from the safe area and 40 from the last "rating view". how do I achieve this?

code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SH1ViewResult: View {
    @State var text: String = "long text long text long text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong text long text"
    @State var userVoice: Bool = false
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false
    @State var score: Int = 69
    var quit: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 50)
                    VStack {
                        ScrollView {
                            Text("\(text)")
                                .padding([.top, .bottom, .leading, .trailing], 12)
                        }
                        .disabled(isExpanded)
                    }
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 32,
                           height: isExpanded ?
                        .infinity :
                            geometry.size.height * 0.40
                    )
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Image("Chevron")
                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 8, height: 13)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                                .padding(.bottom, 4)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    isExpanded = true
                                }
                        }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 32, height: 40)
                            .background(
                                LinearGradient(gradient:
                                                Gradient(colors:
                                                            [Color.green,
                                                             Color.gray]),
                                               startPoint: .top,
                                               endPoint: .bottom
                                              )
                            )
                            .opacity(isExpanded ? 0 : 1),
                        alignment: .bottom
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    HStack(spacing: 24) {
                        Button {
                            print("example sound")
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 108, height: 42)
                        }
                        Button {
                            print("uservoice")
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 108, height: 42)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 16)
                    VStack {
                        RatingStarsView(score: .constant(55),
                                        labelIsShow: .constant(true)
                        )
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 16)
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("first")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            RatingStarsView(score: .constant(72),
                                            labelIsShow: .constant(false)
                            )
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 24)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 64, height: 30)
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("second")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            RatingStarsView(score: .constant(85),
                                            labelIsShow: .constant(false)
                            )
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 64, height: 30)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 22)

                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 8)
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Button {
                            print("button")
                        }  label: {
                            Text("button 1")
                                .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .medium))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 10)
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16 )
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(LightGreenButton())
                        .disabled(userVoice ? true : false)
                        Button {
                            print("tapped next")
                        }  label: {
                            Text("button 2")
                                .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .medium))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 10)
                                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(FilledButton())
                        .disabled(userVoice ? true : false)
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 32)
                }
                .frame(height: isExpanded ? .infinity : geometry.size.height)
            }
            .scrollEnabled(isExpanded)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func scrollEnabled(_ enabled: Bool) -> some View {
        if enabled {
            self
        } else {
            simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0),
                                including: .all)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vStack at outer side to make your hstack bottom like this

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            --- existing code-------- // remove hstack from here and put outside
            Spacer()
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button {
                    print("button")
                }  label: {
                    Text("button 1")
                        .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .medium))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 10)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16 )
                }
                .buttonStyle(.automatic)
                .disabled(userVoice ? true : false)
                Button {
                    print("tapped next")
                }  label: {
                    Text("button 2")
                        .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .medium))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 10)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .disabled(userVoice ? true : false)
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
            .padding([.bottom, .top], 40)
        }
        
    }
```